# Hypotenuse increases non linearly wrt the adjacent

Tags: geometry

I have two right angled triangles

The first one has an Opposite of $2.5$ & a Hypotenuse of $7.5$

The second has an Opposite of $10$ & a Hypotenuse of $45$
The ratio changes with the increase in the value of the opposite.
Please can anyone derive a formula to find the hypotenues when the adjacent is, for example, 1 bearing in mind the changing ratio of triangles 1 & 2

Comment: Which ratio changes? Does the length of the hypotenuse also change?

Comment: Not enough data to pin down the relations among the sides.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio called $\sin$ in the two cases 1,2 is changing!

$$ \sin \alpha = \frac{2.5}{7.5}= \frac{1}{3} $$

$$ \sin \beta = \frac{10}{45} = \frac{1}{4.5} $$

Please note, the ratio changes if either of two, of opposite side or hypotenuse, changes.

The hypotenuse in case 1 is:

$$ \frac{1}{\cos \alpha}$$

and in case 2 is:

$$ \frac{1}{\cos \beta}.$$

EDIT1:

Hypotenuse length =

$$ \frac{adj.  side}{\cos \alpha} \;\; OR \;\; \frac{adj. side}{\cos \beta} $$
OR
$$ \frac{opp.  side}{\sin \alpha} \;\; OR \;\; \frac{opp. side}{\sin \beta} $$

Comment: So the formula for finding the hypotenuse is?

Comment: edited answer. Clear?

Comment: Much clearer, thank you Narasimham

Comment: However, where is the change in the ratio?
In the case 1  the ratio of the length of the hypotenuse to the adjacent is 3:1
In case 2 it's 4.5:1 is what is the increment per unit change in the adjacent?
So to repeat the original question, what would the length of the hypotenuse be if the adjacent was 1 using the decrement ratio of 4.5:1>3:1

Comment: Sorry, confusion in terms.
I MEANT:
However, where is the change in the ratio? In the case 1 the ratio of the length of the hypotenuse to the OPPOSITE is 3:1 In case 2 it's 4.5:1 is what is the increment per unit change in the OPPOSITE ? So to repeat the original question, what would the length of the hypotenuse be if the OPPOSITE was 1 using the decrement ratio of 4.5:1>3:1

Comment: You are probably unable to see that the trig ratio itself is changing. More discussion may entail redirection by mod to chat.

Comment: I can see that the trig ratio is changing, that was the whole point. So first find the ratio of the change of the hypotenuse wrt the change in each increment/decrement of the opposite. then it's solvable for any value of the opposite. eg if the opposite = 1, then using the decrementing ratio of 4.5:1 (for case 2) down to 3:1 (for case 1) it should be possible to find the value for 1 (probably about 1.7:1)